# Default value is not applied in PostgreSQL using COALESCE and inet functions

Tags: postgresql, null, server, constraints, ip-address

I have defined a column in the following way:

```
UserIP INET NOT NULL DEFAULT COALESCE(inet_client_addr(), inet_server_addr())
```

The objective is to store the user ip whenever the query is run from the client side or the server side.

If I run the following query at both sides of the connection, it works:

```
SELECT COALESCE(inet_client_addr(), inet_server_addr())
```

It provides the user ip at the client side and server ip at the server side.

Everything is fine as long as I am running insert from the client side. But when I run it from the server, I get a constraint violation for this field, assuming it is NULL.

```
ERROR:  null value in column "userip" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (36552583, [...] null (null is returned for userip), [...])
```

The `COALESCE` function seems to be ignored.

What am I missing? How could I achieve it either way?

**Update**

I also have a trigger on this table that is triggered on update:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_datap2_user
  BEFORE UPDATE
  ON scientific.datap2
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE scientific.updateuser();
```

Where the trigger function is the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION scientific.updateuser()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    IF ROW(NEW.*) IS DISTINCT FROM ROW(OLD.*) THEN
        NEW.Updated = now()::timestamp; 
        NEW.UserName = current_user;
        NEW.UserIP = COALESCE(inet_client_addr(), inet_server_addr());
        RETURN NEW;
    ELSE
        RETURN OLD;
    END IF;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless there was a typo (in the question), the UPDATE Trigger shouldn't interfere with the INSERT query on the Server side, so that's one complication out of the window.

You should probably have more fallbacks (`127.0.0.1 / 0.0.0.0`) in the `COALESCE` function, since it seems the two options selected don't constitute the universe.

For e.g. when I run this `SQL` from `psql` in bash on the postgres server, I get `NULL` for both the function calls.

```
postgres=# select inet_client_addr();
 inet_client_addr
------------------

(1 row)

postgres=# select inet_server_addr();
 inet_server_addr
------------------

(1 row)

postgres=#
```

You may also err on the side of removing the `NOT NULL` constraints (and thus remove the fallbacks given above) since effectively they are bad data. I'd rather have empty cells than be filtering for magic texts in all my SQLs for eternity.

Additionally, from the [doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-info.html), `All these functions return NULL if the current connection is via a Unix-domain socket.`